# Probability of drawing the king of hearts and a red card

Tags: probability

> Two cards are drawn from a standard deck of cards at the same time. Find:

a) Probability of drawing the King of  hearts and a red card
b) Probability of drawing the King of  hearts and a black card

#### Progress

a) I get a red card and a king hearts: P(R or K). There are 26 reds card out of 52 cards, so P(R) = 26/52 = 1/2. There are 4 kings out of 52 cards, so P(K) = 4/52 = 1/13. There is 1 card which is a red card and a king of hearts so
$$P(\text{H and K}) = \frac{1}{13}\times \frac12 = \frac{1}{26}$$

But I don't know if this is  right.

Comment: yup , I tried it .. a) I get A red card and a king hearts:  P(R or K)      
There are 26 reds card out of 52 cards, so P(R) = 26/52 = 1/2  
There are  4 kings out of 52 cards, so P(K) = 4/52 = 1/13    
There is 1 card which is a red card and a king of hearts    
so P(H and K) = (1/13) x (1/2) = 1/26

Comment: But i don't know right or wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is by a counting procedure. There are $\binom{52}{2}$ two-card hands. They are all *equally likely.*

We now count the *favourables*. There are $25$ hands that have the King of $\heartsuit$ and an additional red card.  For there are $25$ red cards that are not the King of $\heartsuit$.

Thus the required probability is $\frac{25}{\binom{52}{2}}$.

For King of $\heartsuit$ and a black card, it's your turn.

**Another way:** Imagine drawing the cards one at a time (it makes no difference to the probability). We will be happy if (i) we draw the King of $\heartsuit$, and then another red card, or (ii) if we draw a red card other than the King of $\heartsuit$, and then the King of $\heartsuit$.

We find the probability of (1). The probability the first card is the King of $\heartsuit$ is $\frac{1}{52}$. **Given** that this happened, the probability the next card is red is $\frac{25}{51}$. So the probability of (i) is $\frac{1}{52}\cdot \frac{25}{51}$.

The probability of (ii) is the same. Add.

Comment: Hey sir , I thought there are 4 kings out of 52 cards, so P(K) = 4/52 = 1/13 , i can find out King of hearts from here ? Right or wrong ?

Comment: You could say that the probability the first card drawn is a King is $4/52$, and given that it is a King, the probability it is the Heart King is $\frac{1}{4}$, for a probability of $(1/13)(1/4)=1/52$. But it is much quicker to say there is exactly $1$ King of Hearts, so the probability is $1/52$.

Comment: Oh .. I understood .. Thank sir so much :)

Comment: Hey sir , can you tell me concepts involved about it ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to. But if an experiment can result in $N$ *equally likely* outcomes, and if $H$ of those will make us happy, then the probability we will be happy is $\frac{H}{N}$.

Comment: example : #1  mutually exclusive events, 
#2  conditional probability, 
#3  independent events, 
#4  dependent events, #5  odds, 
#6  P(A   B) = P(A) + P(B), 
#7  P(A   B) = P(A) + P(B) – P(A   B), 
#8  P(A | B) = P(B) – P(B   A), what do you will choose # ?

Comment: When we say that an experiment has $N$ possible outcomes, that says in particular that if $a$ and $b$ are distinct outcomes, then $a$ and $b$ cannot simultaneously happen.

Comment: example : YOU HAVE CONCEPT : #1  mutually exclusive events, 
#2  conditional probability, 
#3  independent events, 
#4  dependent events, #5  odds, 
#6  P(A   B) = P(A) + P(B), 
#7  P(A   B) = P(A) + P(B) – P(A   B), 
#8  P(A | B) = P(B) – P(B   A), what do you will choose "CONCEPT" above ?

Comment: The "Another way" solution used conditional probability. So it used $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(B|A)\Pr(A)$. The first way used just counting.

Comment: Ok thanks sir , i get it ^^ !!

Comment: You are welcome.